# Booting from rEFInd only works after selecting windows

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, 20.04, windows-10, refind

After cloning my hdd to ssd with Samsung's Migration tool, the Ubuntu partition was erased.
After installing Ubuntu on dual boot with windows 10 and installing rEFInd (may be something other than rEFInd), I have encountered the following problem when booting:

- Firstly for a very short time (like just a flash) a black screen with a _ appears and the underscore is replaced briefly with [Fail]
- Secondly the rEFInd boot menu appears with both windows and Ubuntu icons
- If i click on Ubuntu the screen goes black and stays that way until the pc is rebooted
- If i click on Windows the Toshiba logo appears (my laptop is from Toshiba) and after like 5 seconds the rEFInd boot menu appears again with both windows and Ubuntu icons
- Then I can click the one I want cause both boot normally

Comment: question is: why have you installed it? Grub works and is supported. `If you're using Linux, you should be aware that several EFI boot loaders are available, so choosing between them can be a challenge. In fact, the Linux kernel can function as an EFI boot loader for itself, which gives rEFInd characteristics similar to a boot loader for Linux`. . . So you might ask there?

Comment: @kanehekili So I tried without rEFInd and got the same result, when I click on Windows the Toshiba logo appears and after like 5 seconds the Grub menus appears again. The [Failed] still appears the first time